# How can I make this modal pop up window to be displayed when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/s2duLtro/

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div><a href="#target-content" id="button">Apeleaza indicatii</a></div>
<div id="target-content">
    <a href="#" class="close"></a>
    <div id="target-inner"></div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
#target-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}

#target-content:target {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}

#target-content #target-inner {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  padding: 159px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  width: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: white;
  color: #34495E;
}

#target-content #target-inner h2 { margin-top: 0; }

#target-content #target-inner code { font-weight: bold; }

#target-content a.close {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #34495E;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}

#target-content a.close:hover { opacity: 0.4; }
```

This window is loaded only when a user clicks on text.

I want this window to be displayed first, when the page loads.
How do I do this?
JQuery is required?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the javascript you've tried? There isn't any in your fiddle.

Comment: can you attach your full code as a code snippet here it self.

Answer (score 0):

All you needed to do was to set the CSS Opacity to 1 and yes you will need `jQuery` to handle this

```
#target-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;     //SET OPACITY to 1
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

Check out the [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/s2duLtro/6/)

Comment: These things I've done in your example ... I can not close window. I want to work and click the window and to load and automatically

Comment: hi...I have updated my fiddle, check it out, its now working as needed

Answer (score 0):

You cannot target pseudo class in javascript. One workaround would be to bind click event to document, filter out event target and toggle a class `.target`:

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        $('#target-content').toggleClass('target', e.target.id === "button");
    });
    $('#button').click();
})
```

```css
#target-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}
#target-content.target {
    pointer-events: all;
    opacity: 1;
}
#target-content #target-inner {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 159px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    width: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: white;
    color: #34495E;
}
#target-content #target-inner h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
#target-content #target-inner code {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#target-content a.close {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #34495E;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}
#target-content a.close:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#target-content" id="button">Apeleaza indicatii</a>
</div>
<div id="target-content"> <a href="#" class="close"></a>https://jsfiddle.net/s2duLtro/#collaborate
    <div id="target-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your CSS to use:

```
display: hidden;
```

Instead of:

```
opacity: 0;
```

Then you can use the following jQuery to load it when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target-content').fadeIn(200);
});
```

If you use the 'fadeIn(200)', then you can also get rid of your transition in your CSS as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s2duLtro/11/  yes it is ok what you say but can not close the window

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CSS on page load with jQuery. Add the following javascript to your page

```
$(function(){
    $("#target-content").css("opacity", "1"); 
});
```

Comment: are you sure that this sample work?can you update my jsdfiddle please?

Comment: How can you close the window? I want to run both the button and automatically when the page loads

Comment: Ive changed the css to work with the display css style. It makes the javascript a bit cleaner. I've updated the jsfiddle to close the overlay on load, open the overlay on link click and close the overlay on click https://jsfiddle.net/s2duLtro/14/